# React Redux - how to work with form data?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react redux, I have to design a basic form with radio buttons in it. Upon submit I want to pass the result to reducer and update the state. I am puzzled with redux, how to update state, initialize state so that I can invoker reducer with initial state.

I am not familiar with redux-forms, I have to do first app without using redux-forms.

So far I have done this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const hobby = [{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Sports",
    "answers": [{
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Badminton",
      "responses": 5
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Swimming",
      "responses": 15
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "Grocery",
    "answers": [{
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Bread",
      "responses": 10
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Cheeze",
      "responses": 5
    }]
  }
];

function hobbyReducer(state, action) {
    if(action.type === "SUBMIT"){
        hobby.map((e)=>{
            if(e.id == action.id){
                e.answers.map((i)=>{
                    if(i.text === action.text){
                        // I think I have to use Object.assign({}, state, {data to be written for update responses count})
                        // Here I have to update the state with incremented value for i.responses
                        // Suppose I choose badminton then i.responses = 15 should be now 16
                        // return updated state
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
    }
  }

handleSubmit(e){
  const store = createStore(hobbyReducer); // created store here
  var k = (document.querySelector('input[name = "hobby"]:checked').value);

  store.dispatch({type:"SUBMIT", text: k, id: 1});  // Dispatching action to reducer
  store.subscribe(()=>{
      console.log(store.getState());
  });
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <input type="radio" value="Badminton" name="hobby" /> Badminton
          <input type="radio" value="Swimming" name="hobby" /> Swimming
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yeah, the question is I couldnot get the updated state. I need help, how can i write the action data to state and return new state.

Comment: I thought posting some code would be helpful for commenters, feeling helpless with current situation im stuck in.

Comment: Try some of the tutorials out there. Come back when you have a specific question. There's definitely a learning curve to React, but you've gotta put in some more work. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic